# Is there a way to move children to another parent if they overflow the current parents height?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I use React to write an web application. I have a `Container` component that serves as a container with fixed height. In this `Container` I have multiple children with different heights. Is there a way to programmatically copy `Container` component and move it's children components that overflow first containers height into copied container. And, if possible, do this recursively ( so we can have multiple copied containers ).

Only example of this that I can think of is page break when you want to print something or write something on a new page in the document but in this case I want to do this on the webpage without any printing.

Here is the code that I currently have:

Container:

```
const Container = ({ children }) => {
  return <div style={{ height: "500px" }}>{children}</div>;
}
```

Page:

````
return (
   <Container> 
       <div style={{ height: 250, width: "100%", border: "2px solid black" }}></div>
       <div style={{ height: 250, width: "100%", border: "2px solid black" }}>
         {/* Elements below should be moved to a new container */}
         <div style={{ height: 200, width: "100%", border: "2px solid black" }}></div>
       </div>
       <div style={{ height: 200, width: "100%", border: "2px solid black" }}></div>
   </Container>
)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Updated with an alternative experimental approach that reads the height of elements with `getBoundingClientRect()`, so that the placement of elements is not relying on set `height` value passed from the props.

Because the element heights need to be detected after their first render, here `PagedContainer` works as a recursive component that dynamically send any elements exceeding the max height to the next container.

The detection logic is quite rough and could still use many improvements, but here is a demo for the experimental approach on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bfmjqr?file=src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

//  Test elements
const Box = React.forwardRef(({ height }, ref) => {
  const bg = {
    100: "lightblue",
    250: "hotpink",
    350: "lightgreen",
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: height || 350,
        height: height || 500,
        backgroundColor: bg[height] || "orange",
      }}
      ref={ref}
    >
      {`${height || 350} x ${height || 500}`}
    </div>
  );
});

//  Recursive paged container component
const PagedContainer = ({ elements, max }) => {
  const [redirectIndex, setRedirectIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const elementsRef = React.useRef([]);

  //  Check heights and send exceeding element to the next container
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const heights = elementsRef.current
      .filter((item) => !!item)
      .map((item) => {
        const { height } = item.getBoundingClientRect();
        return height;
      });
    const newRedirectIndex = heights.findIndex(
      (item, index, arr) =>
        arr.reduce(
          (acc, cur, curIndex) => (curIndex > index ? acc : acc + cur),
          0
        ) > max
    );
    if (newRedirectIndex === -1) return;
    setRedirectIndex(newRedirectIndex);
  }, [elements.length, max]);

  return (
    <>
      <section className="container">
        {elements
          .filter((item, index) =>
            redirectIndex === 0 ? true : index < redirectIndex
          )
          .map(
            (item, index) =>
              item &&
              React.cloneElement(item, {
                ref: (node) => {
                  elementsRef.current[index] = node;
                },
              })
          )}
      </section>
      {!!redirectIndex && (
        <PagedContainer
          elements={elements.filter((item, index) => index >= redirectIndex)}
          max={max}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

//  Componant that creates paged containers
const PagedContainerList = ({ children, maxHeight }) => {
  const max = parseInt(maxHeight, 10) || 500;
  const elements = React.Children.toArray(children);

  return (
    <div className="list">
      <PagedContainer elements={elements} max={max} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = React.useState([]);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="controls">
        <button onClick={() => setBoxes((prev) => [...prev, 100])}>
          Add a box  of height 100
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setBoxes((prev) => [...prev, 250])}>
          Add a box  of height 250
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setBoxes((prev) => [...prev, 350])}>
          Add a box  of height 350
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="frame">
        <PagedContainerList maxHeight={500}>
          <Box height={250} />
          <Box height={100} />
          {boxes.map((item, index) => (
            <Box key={index} height={item} />
          ))}
        </PagedContainerList>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Original**

Assuming that the generated elements have a set `height` in props like the posted example, perhaps this can be implemented by reading and regrouping `Children` based on set `height`, and output the result of a regrouped elements.

Each group of elements can be put in its own container, and could also accept further conditional styling if needed.

Demo of the experimental solution on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rbnfxk?file=src/App.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

//  Test elements
const Box = ({ height }) => {
  const bg = {
    100: 'lightblue',
    250: 'hotpink',
    350: 'lightgreen',
  },
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: height || 350,
        height: height || 500,
        backgroundColor: bg[height] || 'orange',
      }}
    >
      {`${height || 350} x ${height || 500}`}
    </div>
  );
};

//  Componant that creates paged containers
const PagedContainerList = ({ children, maxHeight }) => {
  const items = React.Children.toArray(children);
  const max = parseInt(maxHeight, 10) || 500;

  const indexedHeights = items.map((item, index) => ({
    itemIndex: index,
    height: parseInt(item.props?.height, 10) || 500,
  }));

  //  Group the index of elements with each group not exceeding maxHeight
  const groups = indexedHeights.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (acc.length === 0) return [[cur]];
    const prevSum = acc[acc.length - 1].reduce(
      (acc, cur) => acc + cur.height,
      0
    );
    prevSum + cur.height > max
      ? acc.push([cur])
      : acc[acc.length - 1].push(cur);
    return acc;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="list">
      {/*  Map of paged containers and nested map of children elements */}
      {groups.map((group, index) => (
        <section className="container" key={index}>
          {group.map((item) => (
            <React.Fragment key={item.itemIndex}>
              {items[item.itemIndex]}
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </section>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = React.useState([])
  return (
    <>
    <div className="controls">
      <button onClick={()=>setBoxes(prev=>[...prev, 100])}>Add a box  of height 100</button>
      <button onClick={()=>setBoxes(prev=>[...prev, 250])}>Add a box  of height 250</button>
      <button onClick={()=>setBoxes(prev=>[...prev, 350])}>Add a box  of height 350</button>
    </div>
    <div className="frame">
      <PagedContainerList maxHeight={500}>
        <Box height={250}/>
        <Box height={100}/>
        {boxes.map((item,index)=><Box key={index} height={item}/>)}
      </PagedContainerList>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is very nice solution! Thanks John. I know that I didn't specify this in the initial question but how would we deal with automatic heights ( height: auto ) definitions? Because sometimes it happens that we don't have specified height in React children so how would we get it?

Comment: @szivkovicx Thanks for the reply, finally got some time to update and I've added an experimental approach that does not rely on set height. Although it might not be as predictable so I think having things on controlled sizes still more preferable, if it is possible in the use case.

Comment: This is great! Easy and elegant solution and probably very easy to improve with some detection features. Thanks John!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue to you, and this is how I've fixed it.
I've added it to your code hopefully it will work.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const Container = ({ children }) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const overflowRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current;
    const overflow = overflowRef.current;

    if (container && overflow) {
      if (container.offsetHeight < overflow.offsetHeight) {
        // Move the overflowing elements to a new container
        const newContainer = document.createElement("div");
        newContainer.style.height = `${overflow.offsetHeight - container.offsetHeight}px`;
        newContainer.style.border = "2px solid black";

        while (overflow.firstChild) {
          newContainer.appendChild(overflow.firstChild);
        }

        container.appendChild(newContainer);
      }
    }
  }, [children]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "500px", position: "relative" }} ref={containerRef}>
      <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", position: "absolute" }} ref={overflowRef}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div style={{ height: 250, width: "100%", border: "2px solid black" }}></div>
      <div style={{ height: 250, width: "100%", border: "2px solid black" }}>
        {/* Elements below should be moved to a new container */}
        <div style={{ height: 200, width: "100%", border: "2px solid black" }}></div>
      </div>
      <
```

Comment: Interesting but unfortunately this doesn't solve this. This creates another container inside the container which is not the solution. Solution would be to create a n container in Page component every time elements of the n-1 container overflow the container height ( in this case 500px ).